# Putting JNI primitive types into same array

Tags: java, android, object, casting, java-native-interface

I am trying to write static Java method that with given parameters, searches and invokes Method.

This method is supposed to have variable amount of arguments, and must be called from C++.
I tried few options, but i cannot get it done. Is this even possible?

So far, i can store what types it contains and what position, and i can put jobject and jstring in same array.

If this is not possible, is it possible to refer either methodID found from JNI with Java's reflection or somehow pass reference to object in long. Such structure would be ok, since i can cast 64 bit Integer to everything else.

Comment: I think it might be possible with [run-time type information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

Comment: I think RTTI is disabled in android native not sure.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify android!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that array in JNI, use the jvalue union type as your array type.  Ex: jvalue myArray* = { (jint) 1, (jlong) 1000, (jboolean) false }

Java does not support jvalue nor does it support variadic functions, so if you need to pass that array of primitives to JNI from Java as a way of working around the limitation, you should use an Object array with primitive object wrappers like java.lang.Integer and call the value functions depending on type in JNI.  Its possible, just a pain to implement.

Comment: What would be complexity of so many calls for single execution be? And is it ok initiating all those object?

Comment: Its not going to be excessively slow and why wouldn't it be ok?  The headache implementing it in JNI is just going to be iterating the array and then calling IsInstanceOf followed by some class and method lookups.  After finding the method id for something like objInteger.intValue(), you would call that method to get the jprimitive you want.

Comment: Thank you, i got certain way of doing it. I store those 9 classes as global refs and there constructors methodID's, and use object array. Still cannot test it properly but ill report here if anyone encounters similar problem.